# Can I cache getClass.hashCode()?

Tags: java, jpa, hashcode, premature-optimization

Whatever the reason, I have the following `hashCode` implemented in my abstract class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract Some {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode(); // TODO: cache, maybe?
    }
}
```

1. Can I cache the value of the `getClass().hashCode()`?
2. Is there any possibility of the value being changed while running in a JVM?
3. Is this some kind of the premature optimization shit?

Comment: Without knowing, what do you need it for, it sure  sounds like premature optmization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Can I cache the value of the `getClass().hashCode()`?

You can, but ...

> 2. Is there any possibility of the value being changed while running in a JVM?

No possibility.  The class of a Java object cannot change, and the hashcode of a Java `Class` object (which is the result type for `getClass()`) cannot change.

> 3. Is this premature optimization?

Probably yes<sup>1</sup>.

However, using the hashcode of the object's class as the hashcode of an object is **a very bad idea** from a performance perspective.

Doing that means that all instances of the class (e.g. `Some`) will have the same hashcode<sup>2</sup>.  That will lead to a bazillion hash collisions, and make most `HashSet` and `HashMap` operations `O(N)` or `O(logN)` (depending on your Java version) rather than `O(1)`.

---

<sup>1 - I am assuming you have not done a bunch of performance analysis that you haven't told us about.  If you *had* already done the analysis, then maybe this is not a premature optimization.

2 - I am assuming that the `Some::hashCode` method is not overridden to something more sensible by concrete subclasses of `Some`.</sup>

Comment: That's a good answer. I have one confusion: Can there be multiple instances of a `Class<Some>`, in case of multiple class loaders loading `Some` class. If yes, then In that case, getClass().hashcode() may return different values

Comment: I was talking about multiple class loaders loading `Some` class. Because `getClass().hashcode()` is in `Some` class. So if `Some` class is loaded by multiple class loaders, will `getClass().hashcode()` return different values for both of them?

Comment: Ah ... I misread.  If multiple class loaders load `Some`, then they will be different classes (from the perspective of the Java type system), and they with have different `Class<Some>` objects and their hashcodes will probably be different.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen C's answer is a good answer. However, for the sake of completeness, I feel the need to add to that, that if a class is loaded by, let's say, two different class loaders, then for that class `getClass().hashCode()` will return two different values.

For verifying that, I wrote a program and loaded a class with System class loader, and then with my own custom class loader. Both return different `hashCode()`:

First the code for Custom class loader I copied from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-classloader:

```
package com.journaldev.classloader;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Our Custom ClassLoader to load the classes. Any class in the
 * com.journaldev package will be loaded using this ClassLoader.
 * For other classes, it will delegate the request to its Parent
 * ClassLoader.
 */
public class CCLoader extends ClassLoader {

  /**
   * This constructor is used to set the parent ClassLoader
   */
  public CCLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
    super(parent);
  }

  /**
   * Loads the class from the file system. The class file should be located in
   * the file system. The name should be relative to get the file location
   *
   * @param name Fully Classified name of the class, for example, com.journaldev.Foo
   */
  private Class getClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    String file = name.replace('.', File.separatorChar) + ".class";
    byte[] b = null;
    try {
      // This loads the byte code data from the file
      b = loadClassFileData(file);
      // defineClass is inherited from the ClassLoader class
      // that converts byte array into a Class. defineClass is Final
      // so we cannot override it
      Class c = defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
      resolveClass(c);
      return c;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Every request for a class passes through this method. If the class is in
   * com.journaldev package, we will use this classloader or else delegate the
   * request to parent classloader.
   *
   * @param name Full class name
   */
  @Override
  public Class loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if (name.startsWith("com.journaldev.")) {
      return getClass(name);
    }
    return super.loadClass(name);
  }

  /**
   * Reads the file (.class) into a byte array. The file should be
   * accessible as a resource and make sure that it's not in Classpath to avoid
   * any confusion.
   *
   * @param name Filename
   * @return Byte array read from the file
   * @throws IOException if an exception comes in reading the file
   */
  private byte[] loadClassFileData(String name) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
        name);
    int size = stream.available();
    byte buff[] = new byte[size];
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);
    in.readFully(buff);
    in.close();
    return buff;
  }
}
```

Then the `Test` class and main method which we will use for loading the `Test` class with different class loaders:

```
package com.journaldev.test;

import com.journaldev.classloader.CCLoader;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(new CCLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())
        .loadClass(Test.class.getCanonicalName()).hashCode());
    System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
        .loadClass(Test.class.getCanonicalName()).hashCode());
  }
}
```

Output shows different hashcodes for the same class loaded with different Class Loaders:

```
1554547125
1072591677
```